# Mapserver weird output of REQUEST=GetCapabilities&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1

Tags: wms, web-mapping, mapserver, ubuntu, apache

Once I use REQUEST=GetCapabilities&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1 in my browser with the mapserv I get the following:

> $ cat ~/Downloads/ms

```
ELF>�@@!@8  @@@@��888�� �� � �� �� �   TTTDDP�tdLLQ�tdR�td�� � xx/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2GNUGNU��@%(/���|jx(�|�C�CE��j�|2b������
                                  :�
                                    �K���qX����
                                                ��  є�8����l��w�=�R ���' �"����C �`l ����!3��  �  �e�   g  a
 ibmapserver.so.2_Jv_RegisterClasses_ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable__gmon_start___ITM_registerTMCloneTablemsIO_installHandlersmsResetErrorListmsFreeMapServObjmsDebugloadParamsmsCGIWriteErrormsGetVersionmsCGIWriteLogmsSetupmsGetGlobalDebugLevelmsCGIDispatchRequestmsCGILoadMapmsAllocMapServObjmsCleanupmsIO_setHeaderEnabledlibfcgi.so.0FCGI_AcceptFCGI_freadFCGI_fwrite_fcgi_sFlibc.so.6fflushexitstrncmpsignalputsputchargetpidputenvstdoutgettimeofday__cxa_finalize__libc_start_main_edata__bss_start_end/usr/lib� � � � � � � � �  _used__libc_csu_fini__data_startmsCleanupOnSignalGLIBC_2.2.5�ui   �����  � � � 


        ( 0 8 @ H P X ` h p x � � � � �  � !� "� #� $H�H�E H��t�+H���5 �% @�% h������% h������% h������% h������% h������% h������% h������% h�p����% �`����%� h    �P����%� h
�@����%� h
          �0����%� h
�����%� h�����%� h������%� h������%z h������%r h������%j h������%b h������%Z h������%R h������%J h�p����%B h�`����%: h�P����%2 h�@����%* h�0����%" h� ����% h����AWAVAUATI��U��SH��x�������t1��=��������1��Q����L�����v
H���w�����2�H�=�H��L����H�L9�u�H�5��
 H�L$@H�L$`H�PH�D$(H�� H�D$hH�T$HH�H�T$PL�������������c������vRH��1�������H*L$�H*T��H*D$H�=o�^�^�X��H*
H�����������}-�t����}h�j����}�`���H�=q������                                                                    $X�\�����������1��������E<v���}��H�5��
�r���H�=�����H�=��z���H�=��n���H�=��b���H�=�V���1�������<n�^����}h�T����}�J���1�E1�����������H�=������H�;����������@�����L�H��E1�1�1�1�D�pL�������A�GH�H�߃x����%���H��H�C����H~
��H*D$PH�=D�^�X��H*L$0X�\����1�H���U���H���=������������K���H�������H�,
                                                                              H�8�D���1��}���H���U����L���A������D������55
                                                                                                                             H�=K��1�������
lH�=�����@����f.�DH�                                                                                                                       ����1�I��^H��H���PTL��H�
 H�=
 UH)�H��H�w]�H��
 H��t�]�@H��
 H�=�
 UH)�H��H��H��H��?H�H��u]�H�G
 H��t�]H���@�=m
 u'H�=7
 UH��t
      H�=J
 ������h���]�D
 ��fffff.�H�=� t&H�
 H��tUH�=� H����]�W�����K���f.��1�H�1�1�������L���1������DH�H��Hc�H��������H�@H�H��Hc�H��������H�@AWA��AVI��AUI��ATL�%� UH�-� SL)�1�H��H������H��t�L��L��D��A��H��H9�u�H�[]A\A]A^A_�ff.���H�H��REQUEST_METHOD=GET--helpOptions :fcgiCGI Request %d on process %d
QUERY_STRING=Usage: mapserv [--help] [-v] [-nh] [QUERY_STRING=value]  -h, --help              Display this help message.  -v                      Display version and exit.  -nh                     Suppress HTTP headers in CGI mode.  QUERY_STRING=value      Set the QUERY_STRING in GET request mode.mapserv request processing time (msLoadMap not incl.): %.3fs
mapserv total execution time: %.3fs
��.A;������������h ����@����`��������@�����zRx
                                                         �����*zRx
                                                                           �$ ����FJ
\`���Dth���D4�����GBBB �B(�D0�C8�D�D�8���eBEE �E(�H0�H8�M@l8A0A(B BB �?;*3$"DX���
                                                                                        `�����S�
�� � ���o���                                                                                      �
�
  � ��

�   ���o���o
���o���oZ
���o� &6FVfv����&6FVfv���  41ff45f23492ece94952837828d17cc05e8552.debug`�7�.shstrtab.interp.note.ABI-tag.note.gnu.build-id.gnu.hash.dynsym.dynstr.gnu.version.gnu.version_r.rela.dyn.rela.plt.init.text.fini.rodata.eh_frame_hdr.eh_frame.init_array.fini_array.jcr.dynamic.got.data.bss.gnu_debuglink
                                                                                                                                                88TT !tt$4���o��>
           ���F���N���oZ
Z
d[���o

 j

t�
     �
      �
       ~��y����B��� ��L�PPT�� �� �� �� � �� ��      � 4H �
```

This is the first time I get something like this with Mapserver, I installed 7.0.7 in Linux mint:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep mapserver
ii  cgi-mapserver                                               7.0.7-1~trusty3                                      amd64        CGI executable for MapServer
ii  libmapserver2                                               7.0.7-1~trusty3                                      amd64        Shared library for MapServer
ii  mapserver-bin                                               7.0.7-1~trusty3                                      amd64        MapServer utilities
```

**Update:**

```
$ locate libmapserver
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmapserver.so.2 (symbolic link to `libmapserver.so.7.0.7')
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmapserver.so.7.0.7

http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv
No query information to decode. QUERY_STRING is set, but empty.

http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/mnt/WEBs/gdb.web/extras/map/es/capas.map
mapserv(): Web application error. Traditional BROWSE mode requires a TEMPLATE in the WEB section, but none was provided.
```

Comment: What do you get with `http://your_server.org/cgi_bin/mapserv`, then with `http://your_server.org/cgi_bin/mapserv?map=path/to/your_map.map`. But the response looks like binary code, it can be the mapserv binary.  If you use Apache, have you set the cgi-bin path correctly in httpd.conf? It should look like `ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/...`

Comment: @user30184 please find an update about your suggestions.

Comment: In both cases the response is normal and proves that a) the mapserv cgi-bin program is found and it works and b) that you mapfile is found as well. Nice that you could make your MapServer to work by upgrading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

Add the NextGIS ppa (https://launchpad.net/~nextgis/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) and upgrade the mapserver version:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep mapserv 
ii  cgi-mapserver                                               7.2.1+2-0trusty1                                     amd64        CGI executable for MapServer
ii  libmapserver1                                               7.2.1+2-0trusty1                                     amd64        Shared library for MapServer
ii  mapserver-bin                                               7.2.1+2-0trusty1                                     amd64        MapServer utilities
```